# How can the power of a clinical trial be estimated mid-recruitment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power, clinical-trials

For my PhD I started a three-arm, clinical trial which due to the pandemic I have to stop after having recruited 69 participants instead of 150 originally calculated to give a power of 80%. The trial will continue until completion, but without me and for my PhD thesis I have to analyse the results I have so far. Additionally, due to abrupt halt of the recruitment, the three arms are not even.

If I analyse the power now, would it be considered an interim power analysis or post-hoc power analysis, since these are the results I am presenting and the power analysis is not going to affect the sample size of the continuing trial?

In Zhang et al., 2019 (doi: 10.1136/gpsych-2019-100069) it is stated that post-hoc power analysis can mislead. Is there another way to assess the strength, accuracy or error of my results?

Comment: Do you plan to recruit more patients? Have you already analysed the data?

Comment: I do not plan to recruit more patients and I have analysed the data. Some statistically significant outcomes were found in the between and within group comparisons. The fact that this significance was discovered, did not affect the decision on recruitment discontinuation.

Comment: Among published trials that did not meet their enrollment, I have seen both calculation of power achieved and simple statements that enrollment was not met. If you followed your analysis plan and found some difference in the prespecified outcome(s), you don’t have a power issue per se (ie, no type II error). It would seem that you are on safe ground to make a conclusion or pursue another study.